# How Do I Make Li Boxes Line Up If They Contain Variable Length Text?

Tags: html, css

I am using an unordered list with li items to display multiple boxes across the page, and onto multiple lines. Each box contains variable text length which pushes up the height of some of the boxes. [Here's the example](http://webref.eu/test-uniform-box-size.htm).

How do I get all rows of boxes to line up across the page nicely?

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: well if you want to prevent elements from defining their own height, define one for them and give them a scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
#divOnPageMenu ul {
display: flex;
...
}
```